# Getting style of an element from css file with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I wanna get a style of an element from css file with javascript. But, i just can getting only elements i enter style properties on javascript.  I tried like this on Angular;

```
angular.element(document.getElementById("box")).css("width")
```

It's not worked. After, i tried like this;

```
document.getElementById("box").style
```

But it's not worked. How can i accomplish this?

Comment: It could be because you are searching for an element that is not loaded in the DOM yet.

Try to add your code inside,

angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        document.getElementById("box").style

 });

Comment: document.getElementById("box").style.width is what you are loooking for

Comment: I can't use 'ready function', because i don't use jquery. @PraveenAlluri

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't an Angular issue, it's just how CSS and Javascript interact.  You need to use `getComputedStyle` to read style properties that were defined in a CSS file.

```js
// This will work (because it's an inline style)
console.log(document.getElementById('a').style.width)

// This won't work (because the style was defined in css):
console.log(document.getElementById('b').style.width)

// getComputedStyle will work regardless of the source:
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('b')).width)
```

```css
#b {width: 100px}
```

```html
<div id="a" style="width: 100px">A</div>
<div id="b">B</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get css template rule values of elements calling style properties unless they were set 
*1. using inline style on html element level; or 
*2. the style property has been set using JavaScript

which does the same: writes to inline html style property of the target element.

the solution is to use the computed style instead:

as in : `getComputedStyle(box,0).width`